# circuitikz vs. tikzpicture: generating multipage standalone documents for animations

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz, standalone, animations, gif

This is a problem I found a while ago, and haven't been able to figure out. Maybe is something wrong with my distribution, but don't know exactly how to fix it. Here is the idea

Consider this script

```
\documentclass[border = 5pt, tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
\foreach \k in {1,...,10}
{
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0, 0) rectangle (2, 2);
  \fill[red] (\k/5, 1) circle (0.1);
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{document}
```

When I run it, it produces `10` pages which then I can use to produce a `gif`

[image]

If on the other hand I change the enviroment to `circuitikz`

```
\documentclass[border = 5pt, tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
\foreach \k in {1,...,10}
{
\begin{circuitikz}
  \draw (0, 0) rectangle (2, 2);
  \fill[red] (\k/5, 1) circle (0.1);
\end{circuitikz}
}
\end{document}
```

I get one single page with all frames on it

[image]

and then transforming this to a `gif` has proven a bit difficult to do.

Any ideas as to why this is happening? Thanks!

I'm using `Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (TeX Live 2018/MacPorts 2018.47642_7)`

Comment: I didn't know that `standalone` could produce more than a single page document.

Comment: @Sigur Many animations are produced by producing a multipage pdf first and then convert this to an animated gif via `convert -density <density> -delay <delay> -loop 0 -alpha remove multipage.pdf anited.gif`.

Comment: @marmot, this I know. But I suppose that the pdf can not come from a `standalone` class file.

Comment: @Sigur Yes, it does. If you compile the fist file in the above question, you get a multipage pdf.

Comment: Btw, shouldn't animated SVG be the preferred format nowadays ;-) ?

Comment: The tikz option not only loads tikz, it also sets [multi=tikzpicture] (which is not always a good thing to do).  [multi={circuitikz,tikzpicture}] is what you want.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you say `\documentclass[border = 5pt, tikz]{standalone}` this does not just load `tikz` but also tells `standalone` that it should produce single pdf pages for each `tikzpicture`. In order to generate separate pdf pages for circuitikz you could do

```
\documentclass[border = 5pt, tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\standaloneenv{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\foreach \k in {1,...,10}
{
\begin{circuitikz}
  \draw (0, 0) rectangle (2, 2);
  \fill[red] (\k/5, 1) circle (0.1);
\end{circuitikz}
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that this possibility is not unique. Another possibility is to use

```
\documentclass[border = 5pt, multi={circuitikz}]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\foreach \k in {1,...,10}
{
\begin{circuitikz}
  \draw (0, 0) rectangle (2, 2);
  \fill[red] (\k/5, 1) circle (0.1);
\end{circuitikz}
}
\end{document}
```

instead. For further information, please consult the `standalone` manual on p. 10.

Comment: Note to myself: next time ask sooner :) Thanks a bunch

Comment: This MWE will be very useful in the future.

Answer (score 3):

The same as an animated SVG, using the `animations` library of TikZ/Pgf-3.1:

[image]

Compile with

```
latex example
dvisvgm --zoom=-1 example
```

`example.tex`:

```
\documentclass[dvisvgm]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{animations}

\begin{document}

\begin{circuitikz}
  \draw (0, 0) rectangle (2, 2);
  \scoped [name=circle, animate = {
      object=circle, :shift = { 0s = "{(1/5,1)}", 3s = "{(2,1)}", repeats }
    }
  ] \fill[red] (0,0) circle (0.1);
\end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Amazing, was this introduced in 3.1?